# Current status based on week number ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, calendar, oracle-sqldeveloper

I got this query on order to get all the days from the first day of the year (01/01/2018) to the end of next year (31/12/2019).

```
SELECT MYDATE,
TO_CHAR(NR_OF_SUNDAYS + 1,'FM09') WEEK_NUM,
FROM
(
SELECT MYDATE,
( (TRUNC(MYDATE,'DAY') - TRUNC(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DAY')) / 7 ) +
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DAY') = 'SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NR_OF_SUNDAYS
FROM
( SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') - 1 + LEVEL AS MYDATE
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 24), 'YY') -
TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY')
)
)
```

I need a column that specifies the following cases:

- 1) CASE WHEN MYDATE < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') THEN 'PAST DUE'
  (this works its easy and no problem)
- 2) if my current =< mydate
  week_num then 'CURRENT WEEK'(Excluding PAST DUE)
- 3) if my current week + one week then
  'NEXT WEEK' (Excluding PAST DUE)
- 4) else FUTURE

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you wrote that query which you are showing, you should easily be able to find solution to rest of the problems, isn't it? where are you stuck?

Comment: `MYDATE` is a `DATE` value, you should not compare it with a CHAR! Just write `CASE WHEN MYDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) THEN 'PAST DUE'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in my answer I tried retain the logic behind your week number calculation.

However keep in mind that you could calculate week number using oracle `to_char(date,'WW')`, `to_char(date,'IW')`, `to_char(date,'W')` functions and then your life would be easier.

```
WW  Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year.
W   Week of month (1-5) where week 1 starts on the first day of the month and ends on the seventh.
IW  Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.
```

Having said all that here is my solution that uses only sql (note that defining and using a function would be a lot easier), based on **your** calculation method.

```
with date_table as (
SELECT MYDATE, to_number(TO_CHAR(NR_OF_SUNDAYS + 1,'FM09')) WEEK_NUM,  to_number(to_char(MYDATE+1,'IW')) as nu
FROM
(
SELECT MYDATE,
( (TRUNC(MYDATE,'DAY') - TRUNC(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DAY')) / 7 ) +
CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american') = 'SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NR_OF_SUNDAYS
FROM
( SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') - 1 + LEVEL AS MYDATE
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 24), 'YY') -TRUNC (SYSDATE,'YY')
)
)
),
todays_week as 
(
select distinct WEEK_NUM from date_table 
where trunc(sysdate)=trunc(mydate)
),
pre_final as (
select MYDATE,WEEK_NUM, (select  WEEK_NUM from todays_week) as todaysweek from date_table)
select MYDATE,sysdate,WEEK_NUM,todaysweek,
case when trunc(MYDATE) < trunc(sysdate) then 'PAST DUE' 
     when todaysweek = WEEK_NUM and abs(MYDATE-sysdate)<=7 then 'CURRENT WEEK'
     when todaysweek +1 = WEEK_NUM and abs(MYDATE-sysdate)<=14 then 'Next Week'
     else 'Future' end as description
     from pre_final;
```

The main idea is to find today's week number and then use `case when`.

Here is my fiddle link with the results. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3149e4/148

**EDIT 1**:
Now, similar results one could achive with something like this:

```
select res.*,
case when trunc(MYDATE) < trunc(sysdate) then 'PAST DUE' 
     when todaysweek = WEEK_NUM and abs(MYDATE-sysdate)<=7 then 'CURRENT WEEK'
     when todaysweek +1 = WEEK_NUM and abs(MYDATE-sysdate)<=14 then 'Next Week'
     else 'Future' end as description
 from (
SELECT MYDATE, to_number(to_char(MYDATE,'IW')) as WEEK_NUM,to_number(to_char(sysdate,'IW')) as todaysweek 
FROM
( SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') - 1 + LEVEL AS MYDATE
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 24), 'YY') -TRUNC (SYSDATE,'YY')
)) res
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Deluq you are welcome  :)  Note that I edited my answer in order to deal with  same week numbers of the  next year...  otherwise you would get two sets  of `current week` and `next week`.

Comment: Yeah, fortunately I am using this table only to bring up 1 month ahead planning orders.

Comment: `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DAY')` would return `"SUNDAY   "`  - not `"SUN"`, use `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = american')` I wonder how this query can provide desired result.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit apperanlty this part `CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MYDATE,'YYYY'),'DAY') = 'SUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` is always `0` and does not play any part in calculations. I left OPs query as it was without investigating it further. Howerever, now that you point this out -  It is obvious that you are correct.

Comment: You would get wrong results for year 2017 or 2023. For other years it does not matter.